# How to define multiple tasks in elastic beanstalk docker json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on application where I use multicontainer docker Elastic Beanstalk. I have one Dockerrun.aws.json where I define 10 containers. The problem is that I need more than 10 containers on my instance, but AWS allow only 10 container task definition in one Dockerrun.aws.json. In addition, I need to use Elastic Beanstalk because that's how I deploy the new code to the containers. Can you give be advise the best approach for my problem.

I found that if we can tag 10 containers as one task and the rest as second task, this is possible. But, I cannot figure out how to define my json to have multiple tasks

Any help is very much appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm looking at doing the same thing right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately**, Elastic Beanstalk multicontainer docker takes care of Task creation and definition and will **only support one/single Task definition per environment**. see [slide 19](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-microservices-and-docker#19) and [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html).